# undetected-chromedriver does not quit properly after script execution is complete

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I use `driver.quit()` at the end of my code, and it closes the Chrome window as expected, but when checking Task Manager on Windows after script execution is complete, I find Chrome tasks that are eating up the CPU - and I'm certain that those tasks are from undetected-chromedriver

here is a screenshot [image: screenshot]

did anyone face this issue, and how do I make sure that undetected-chromedriver terminates properly and does not leave any running background tasks?

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue before as I was using subprocess `driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)`. just remove that option and use `driver = uc.Chrome()` and it should terminate properly.

Comment: I am also facing this issue but can not get it working. Anyone found another solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase)'s undetected-chromedriver mode for optimal use:

`pip install seleniumbase`, and then run the following script with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver
import time

driver = Driver(uc_cdp=True, incognito=True)
driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
time.sleep(8)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know why but this worked for me. I've tested it on multiple machines and multiple times.
`options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).